# Joomla 2.5 Menu Buttons Not Working

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools, joomla2.5

I'm building a Joomla website and I've now encountered a problem as the buttons have stopped working. These are the Save, Save and Close, Cancel etc buttons in the top right.

I can select from the lists under extensions, modules etc but when I click on a button it says "Please first make a selection from the list" so I can't do anything with them.

I'm wondering if my javascript has been corrupted.

The last thing I was working on was my default.css file and earlier I'd been uploading images via ftp (cyberduck). Would this have corrupted any files?

The version I'm using is Joomla 2.5.6. I'm also working with the Seblod CCK within Joomla.

I've seen Mootools mentioned in forums but I can't enable/disable this to test because of the issue explained above with selection.

I'd appreciate any help/advice anyone can give on this.

Comment: Do you have the project hosted online, so we can see the issue live?

Answer (score 0):

if possible enable the debug mode and see if there is any message showing where the issue is coming from. you don't have to do this on the backend you can edit the configuration.php and change the public $debug = '0'; to public $debug = '1';